# Calculating the size of an effervescent tablet

Tags: flow

An effervescent tablet is dropped into water. Find it's size as a function of time.

It's a question from the Rudolph Ortvay Competition '97.
How do I proceed?

Comment: What assumptions do you think you need to make? Is the rate of effervescence constant? Does it start to float at a certain size (after which the top surface is no longer reacting?) Do you assume the table to be cylindrical? Is the concentration in the liquid (and thus the reaction rate) constant? So many assumptions to make...

Comment: I'm sorry. I literally quoted the exact question. But I do think that the table can be considered cylindrical. The reaction rate is probably constant too.